# Unreliable results while obtaining long-lived token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

I am following the FB instructions on access tokens here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

They say to get a short-lived token from the client using the Javascript SDK, which I have done. I obtain a valid short-lived token every time during testing without any problems.

Then on the server I make a cURL request to a URL structured like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=[short-lived-token-here]&client_id=[client-ID-here]&client_secret=[client-secret-here]
```

This does work about 10% - 30% of the time and I get a successful response like:

```
{"access_token":"[LONG-TERM-TOKEN-HERE]","token_type":"bearer"}
```

However 70% - 90% of the time I receive an error like:

```
OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to graph.facebook.com:443
```

It is completely random as to when it works and when it doesn't.
This is what my cURL code looks like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authority: graph.facebook.com';
$headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
   echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I used this because it is what was successfully called in my browser when I go to the URL. However I did also try stripping out the unnecessary headers too and got equally unpredictable results.

It seems like it has nothing to do with request limits as I am at <1% of my app's quota. I have also tried waiting >10 seconds between cURL requests and that doesn't affect the results.

**The weird things is that FB does seem to give me a valid access code every time I perform this request in an actual web browser. This problem only exists when using cURL - even though my PHP cURL request is identical to my browser's XHR request.**

Is there a better way to do this, perhaps with the PHP SDK?

I also tried adding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
```

**EDIT:** After adding `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`, I got the following extra logs:

```
*   Trying 2a03:2880:f034:112:face:b00c:0:2:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to graph.facebook.com (::1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
  CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to graph.facebook.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
Error:OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to graph.facebook.com:443
```

Comment: The error has to do with SSL not the request parameter or the URL. The browser and curl most likely implemented SSL in different ways and for some reason curl in PHP is having problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Any idea on why I would get it sometimes rather than others.

Answer (score 0):

This is less of an answer and more of a workaround. I tried many different configurations with cURL - none of them were reliable.

However I found one simple method to work 100% of the time, which was to use `file_get_contents()`.